# Run Windows service from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, impersonation

I am trying to start/stop service form ASP.net (webform). But when I start my code, I get exception

> "**Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid**".

But when I try to start this one service from Management console it start "OK" without any error. This service is run from "Adm" local user.
OS is Windows 10.

```
Impersonate context = new Impersonate(".", "Adm", "5555");
if (context.impersonateValidUser())
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController("Test");
    service.Start();
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET runs on IIS or from server so the context or scope is different from what when you run it from console. I'm not sure even if its possible.

Comment: Thanks, really when i moved from IIS express to regular,  impersonate works correctly.